# Using wildcards with scala.sys.process._ in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to use `scala.sys.process._` package to copy all files from one directory to another in scala like so:

```
s"cp -R $testDir/data/* $dataDir/".!!
```

But I keep getting following error:

```
[error] cp: cannot stat '/tmp/data/*': No such file or directory
```

If I don't put `*` then whole `data` directory is getting copied to the destination folder which is not what I want!

The files in the `data` directory are gzip files which I need to further uncompress like so:

```
s"gunzip $dataDir/data/*".!!
```

But even this throws similar error.

How can I use `*` in commands using `scala.sys.process` in Scala?

Comment: `*` is bash syntax, it only works on bash.

Comment: What's alternative in Scala then?

Comment: This blog explains `find` as an exception to the rule of using "/bin/sh -c". Refer: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-handle-wildcard-characters-running-external-commands/